# writing unban command, discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

when i trie to unban user with "&unban donut_exe_", i get "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'" error
Code below:

```
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="&", help_command=None, intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print("Huligan online")
    
#Приветствие
@client.command( pass_contex = True )

async def greeting(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Пр")
    
#Очистка чата
@client.command( pass_contex = True )
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)

async def clear(ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
    
#Кик    
@client.command( pass_contex = True )
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)

async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Участник {member.mention} был кикнут по причине «{reason}» администратором {ctx.message.author.mention}")
    
#Бан
@client.command( pass_contex = True )
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)

async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Участник {member.mention} был забанен по причине «{reason}» администратором {ctx.message.author.mention}")
    
#Разбан
@client.command( pass_contex = True )
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)

async def unban(ctx, id: str):
    user = id
    await ctx.guild.unban(user)
    await ctx.send(f"Участник {member.mention} был разбанен администратором {ctx.message.author.mention}")





    
token = open("token.txt", r)readline()
client.run(token)
```

I hope you will help me, mb i specified wrong args

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass the ID of the User, not their name.
You can obtain a users ID by right-clicking their portrait (If developer mode is turned on), and clicking "Copy User ID" at the bottom

How to enable Developer mode:

1. Open up the Discord app
2. Click on the settings cog in the bottom left corner
3. Go to Appearance -> allll the way at the bottom
4. Toggle "Developer Mode" on

Additionally you'll have to instantiate a discord object with the id (as an integer) before passing it to the unban function

```
user_id = int(id)
user = discord.Object(id=user_id)
await ctx.guild.unban(user)
```

Comment: That didn't work either, same error'

Comment: I've edited my answer, give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks bro it worked, I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could test this

Unban with userping:

```
unban <@{id of the user}>
```

Unban with id:

```
unban {id of the user}
```

Here is the code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()

    # Check if the provided argument is a mention (user ID)
    if member.startswith('<@') and member.endswith('>'):
        # Extract the user ID from the mention
        user_id = int(member[2:-1])
        user = discord.Object(id=user_id)
    else:
        # Search for the user by name and discriminator
        member_name, _, member_discriminator = member.partition('#')
        for ban_entry in banned_users:
            user = ban_entry.user
            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                break
        else:
            # If user not found, return and notify
            await ctx.send("Участник с таким именем не найден в списке забаненных.")
            return

    await ctx.guild.unban(user)
    await ctx.send(f"Участник {user.mention} был разбанен администратором {ctx.author.mention}")
```

Comment: Nah that didn't work, I get this error:
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression